# SQL Transform a Shift Times into One Hour Increments

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 and I have a table with a list of shifts with their start and end times.   See example data here for what it looks like:

```
    Declare @MyTable as Table   (
        row_index int identity (1,1),
        id varchar(6) not null,
        date varchar(10) not null,
        shift_number int not null,
        shift_start datetime not null,
        shift_stop datetime not null
    )

Insert @MyTable Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 1, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000')
Insert @MyTable Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 2, '1900-01-01 11:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 13:30:00.000')

Select * from @MyTable
```

As you can see, each shift spans multiple hours.  I'm looking for a way to transform that into something like this:

```
Declare @MyTable2 as Table
    (
        row_index int identity (1,1),
        id varchar(6) not null,
        date varchar(10) not null,
        shift_number int not null,
        shift_start datetime not null,
        shift_stop datetime not null,
        hour_number int not null,
        hour_start datetime not null,
        hour_stop datetime not null
    )

Insert @MyTable2 Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 1, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000', 1, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 09:00:00.000')
Insert @MyTable2 Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 1, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000', 2, '1900-01-01 09:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:00:00.000')
Insert @MyTable2 Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 1, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000', 3, '1900-01-01 10:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000')

Insert @MyTable2 Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 2, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000', 1, '1900-01-01 11:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 12:00:00.000')
Insert @MyTable2 Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 2, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000', 2, '1900-01-01 12:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 13:00:00.000')
Insert @MyTable2 Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 2, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000', 3, '1900-01-01 13:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 13:30:00.000')

Select * from @MyTable2
```

Is there an easy way to do this without using some convoluted looping system?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expanded test table. Try my solution.
Edited by comment: 2015-10-26

```
      Declare @MyTable as Table   (
            row_index int identity (1,1),
            id varchar(6) not null,
            date varchar(10) not null,
            shift_number int not null,
            shift_start datetime not null,
            shift_stop datetime not null,
            hourCnt int  -- I added this field
        )


Insert @MyTable Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 1, '1900-01-01 08:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:30:00.000',0)
Insert @MyTable Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 2, '1900-01-01 11:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 15:30:00.000',0)
Insert @MyTable Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 3, '1900-01-01 18:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 19:00:00.000',0)
Insert @MyTable Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 4, '1900-01-01 20:00:00.000', '1900-01-01 20:00:00.000',0)
Insert @MyTable Values ('A', '01-02-2015', 5, '1900-01-01 23:00:00.000', '1900-01-02 01:20:00.000',0)


--Select * from @MyTable

----------

-- we can set this inside to MAINpart
-- but this way is more simple for understanding
update @MyTable
set hourCnt = datediff(hour,shift_start,shift_stop)

declare @MaxHourCnt int
select @MaxHourCnt=max(hourCnt)+2 from @MyTable

-- MAINpart
select my.*, fromto.n as hour_number, 
    dateadd(hour, fromto.n-1, my.shift_start) as hour_start,
    dateadd(hour, fromto.n, my.shift_start) as hour_stop
into #MyTable
from @MyTable my
cross join (
        SELECT TOP (@MaxHourCnt) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)
        FROM [master]..spt_values 
        ORDER BY n
    ) as fromto
where fromto.n<=my.hourCnt+1
   and dateadd(hour, fromto.n-1, my.shift_start)<shift_stop

-- fixing stop values
update #MyTable
set hour_stop=shift_stop
where hour_stop>shift_stop

select * from #MyTable
drop table #MyTable
```

Comment: That is fantastic!   It's very close to the desired output.   Is there any way we can make it include an additional hour for shifts not ending exactly on the hour?   In your example, shift 1 should have 3 hours with the last one being 10am - 10:30am.   Currently, hour 2 spans across an hour and a half.

Comment: @mattyd , I fixed mistake. I looked at an example not attentively first time. Try now ;-)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!  Saved me from crazy loops as I'm a novice at best when it comes to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calendar table for this... or rather an hours table.

Build a table that has each hour you're interested in tracking, then `JOIN` to it with `BETWEEN`.  You'll need a `CASE` expression since you don't have only even hours to bring back results as you want them:

```
SELECT a.*
      ,hour_start = hours
      ,hour_end = CASE WHEN DATEADD(hour,1,hours) > shift_stop THEN shift_stop ELSE DATEADD(hour,1,hours) END
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN lkp_hours b
  ON b.hours BETWEEN shift_start AND shift_stop
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/253df2/3/0)

Note:  You'll need additional logic if shifts can start on half hours as well, and it might make sense to have shorter intervals in your lookup and then filter out the odd-hour items.

Comment: Ah. I forgot to mention that shifts can actually start at any 5 minute increment.  This isn't employee shifts, but rather equipment shifts.  The final hour of the shift may not be a complete hour as a result.  Any ideas for that?